# I am unable to install Java in my Windows 10 machine

Tags: java, windows, windows-10, windows-10-desktop

I am trying to install Java JDK on my Windows 10 machine

on clicking on the EXE I am displayed with a message saying

"Do you want to allow this app to make changes to your device?"

When I click on "Yes" option. window popup disappears but the installation never starts. please refer attached screenshot.

Thank you.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BhAf.jpg)file

Comment: are you on airplane mode ? although exe's size is 205 MB there's a chance the installation needs the web. 

also, it is better to start it from the command line and not from the Explorer.

Comment: have you tried right clicking and running as administrator?

Comment: @ShaharT Right. For some reason my laptop is in airplane mode. But yet connected to WiFi. I tried getting off the airplane mode. Same results.

Answer (score 1):

Does your antivirus software block the installation?

Read through [THIS](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-networking/how-to-install-java-on-windows/a53547f0-310f-4d98-9024-2cb0d3e8b12e?auth=1) comprehensive guide on how to install Java when it will not install, and don't skip any steps (like clean reboots) as they do matter.

Comment: This did not work. I think this is spefically if we see 1603 error as mentioned in the article.

Comment: Any help please. Anyone? Still this issue is not fixed. Without java. My laptop is of no use.

Comment: Try installing the JDK version, then just uninstalling the Dev Kit part of the install, leaving you with just the proper Java Runtime Environments. And also disable any antivirus software ( including windows security ). Or try installing it in safe mode.